# update table according to condition

Tags: mysql

i have to get type from one table  which is set("student","staff'"), and according to the result I have to update staff  or student_class_attendance table I try this

```
SELECT TYPE  
CASE    WHEN TYPE = 'staff' THEN
        UPDATE  staff_attendance SET statues = 1 WHERE staff_id = (SELECT type_id FROM rfid_details WHERE rfid_no = '124' )     
WHEN TYPE = 'student' THEN
    UPDATE  student_class_attendance SET statues = 1 WHERE student_id = (SELECT type_id FROM rfid_details WHERE rfid_no = '124' )
END 
FROM rfid_details WHERE rfid_no = '124'
```

and also

```
SELECT TYPE  IF(TYPE = staff, 
UPDATE staff_attendance 
SET    statues = 1 
WHERE  staff_id = 

          SELECT type_id 
          FROM   rfid_details 
          WHERE  rfid_no = '124' ,UPDATE student_class_attendance 
SET    statues = 1 
WHERE  student_id= 

          SELECT type_id 
          FROM   rfid_details 
          WHERE  rfid_no = '124' ) FROM rfid_details WHERE rfid_no = '124'
```

but shows

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE      WHEN TYPE = 'staff' THEN
>           UPDATE  staff_attendance SET statues = 1 WHER' at line 2

and for if

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF(type = staff, 
>   update staff_attendance 
>   SET    statues = 1 
>   WHERE  staff_i' at line 1

plz help to solve this

Comment: Don't place the logic, which table to update, into the SQL. Do that in the surrounding programming language.

Comment: You need a comma after the `TYPE`. This doesn't seem to be PHP related.

Comment: In the future please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks. I'm can't read the second query... and can't edit it because someone else already tried to fix it.

Comment: Not possible in SQL to do dynamic UPDATE queries like this.. The best you can do this is make a updateable view.. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/inserting-and-updating-with-views/

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't update inside a select statement. You can try the following:

```
UPDATE  staff_attendance SET statues = 1 WHERE staff_id = (SELECT type_id FROM rfid_details WHERE rfid_no = '124' and type = 'staff');
UPDATE  student_class_attendance SET statues = 1 WHERE student_id = (SELECT type_id FROM rfid_details WHERE rfid_no = '124' and type = 'student');
```